# JSON parsing error when reading from URL C#

Tags: c#, json, newtons-method

I am trying to read a JSON file from a URL. The JSON file has a header and some details that I need. Unfortunately, this is my first time doing this, so I would appreciate any guidance you can provide.

The error I am getting is a JSON parsing error.
url:https://api.nobitex.ir/v2/trades/BTCUSDT

```
        public class Trade
        {
            public object time { get; set; }
            public string price { get; set; }
            public string volume { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class Example
        {
            public string status { get; set; }
            public IList<Trade> trades { get; set; }
        }
/*******************************************************/
     string url = "https://api.nobitex.ir/v2/trades/BTCUSDT";

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("err: " + response.StatusCode);
                    return;
                }

                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var st = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Example>>(json); ;


                foreach (var t in st)
                {
             
                    Console.WriteLine("status: " + t.status);
                    Console.WriteLine("trade: " + t.trades);
                }


                var det = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Trade>>(json); ;

                foreach (var d in det)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("status: " + d.volume);
                    Console.WriteLine("status: " + d.type);
                    Console.WriteLine("status: " + d.time);
                    Console.WriteLine("status: " + d.price);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to deserialize into a *collection*:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Example>>(json);
```

But the JSON to which you link isn't an array, it's an object:

```
{"status":"ok","trades":[{"time":1709824308663,"price":"66699.9","volume":"0.009622","type":"buy"},{"time":1709824290203,"price":"66458","volume":"0.000131","type":"sell"},{"time":1709824288176,"price":"66458","volume":"0.000617","type":"sell"},{"time":1709824288176,"price":"66460","volume":"0.000935","type":"sell"},{"time":1709824288176,"price":"66460.01","volume":"0.000001","type":"sell"},{"time":1709824288176,"price":"66460.01","volume":"0.000439","type":"sell"},{"time":1709824206312,"price":"66456.01","volume":"0.003139","type":"sell"},{"time":1709824199600,"price":"66748.97","volume":"0.001498","type":"buy"},{"time":1709824174337,"price":"66750","volume":"0.020422","type":"buy"},{"time":1709824174337,"price":"66700","volume":"0.001","type":"buy"},{"time":1709824165632,"price":"66456","volume":"0.000816","type":"sell"},{"time":1709824165632,"price":"66503","volume":"0.000133","type":"sell"},{"time":1709824165632,"price":"66551","volume":"0.0003","type":"sell"},{"time":1709824165632,"price":"66561.01","volume":"0.00044","type":"sell"},{"time":1709824165632,"price":"66600","volume":"0.000658","type":"sell"},{"time":1709824165632,"price":"66750","volume":"0.00837","type":"sell"},{"time":1709824152591,"price":"66750","volume":"0.019845","type":"sell"},{"time":1709824152591,"price":"66750","volume":"0.011308","type":"sell"},{"time":1709824152591,"price":"66765","volume":"0.000229","type":"sell"},{"time":1709824152591,"price":"66765","volume":"0.000403","type":"buy"}]}
```

This appears to be a single instance of `Example`, so deserialize it to just that one instance:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(json);
```

Comment: tnx JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(json); is work and recive status :ok
 How to deserialize JSON into a list of  *****Trade**** objects?
```

Comment: @محمدحسینمظفری: What do you mean?  The JSON shown already contains that data.  Are you claiming that the `trades` property on the resulting object is empty in some way?  Please clarify the problem.

Comment: yes ! i need get value trades . time and price and volume and type  
{"status":"ok",
trades":[{"time":1709824557266,"price":"66600.1","volume":"0.000273","type":"sell"}]}

Comment: @محمدحسینمظفری: And what stops you from reading that data?  If you are claiming that the deserialization is still failing in some way, please clarify that problem.

Comment: I got the status value from the way you said. But I need to loop (foreach) over the trades and get the internal values of the trades, do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @محمدحسینمظفری: I understand what you mean, but what you haven't clarified is what *stops you* from doing this.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  Even a [cursory test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BqhB6f) demonstrates that you can loop over those records, so what isn't working in your code?

Comment: tnnnnnx ! 
Your link solved my problem